# No error form sql query write character to int colum

Tags: mysql

In my MySql-Database this query does not throw an error or something to indicate that it did not update the fields value. Job_amount is formated as int(11).

```
UPDATE `workflow` SET `job_amount`= "7331fu" WHERE job_id = 1337;
```

Is there a way to know if my query failed?

Comment: what was the problem or error

Comment: What was the exact error message?  This is probably the most useful piece of information you have.

Comment: Try to replace double quotes for single ones: "7331fu" by '7331fu' to unmask the error.

Comment: if you do not give more explaination i give a down-vote for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx for the help. Solution was to use the single quotes and then look for the effected rows.